# HTTP Basic Auth - Can't connect

Tags: ruby, api, authentication, basic-authentication, httparty

I'm unable to fetch anything from the [Wakatime](https://wakatime.com) API, and I don't know what is wrong.

The Documentation states:

> Authentication to the API can be done using HTTP Basic Auth or by adding your api key as a query parameter in your request url like `?api_key=XXXX`. Using HTTP Basic Auth, your username is your API key base64 encoded. Your password is not needed to authenticate.
>
> For example, when using HTTP Basic Auth with an API key of 12345 you should add this header to your request:

```
Authorization: Basic MTIzNDU=
```

I'm using HTTParty to handle the request:

> https://wakatime.com/api/v1/users/theminijohn?api_key=XXX

```
HTTParty.get('https://wakatime.com/api/v1/users/@theminijohn?api_key=XXX')
```

But this returns:

```
{
  "error": "Not found"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

- --> [Wakatime API](https://wakatime.com/developers/)
- --> Api key: XXX
- --> username: theminijohn - https://wakatime.com/@theminijohn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide **user id** in API endpoint, not *username*.

Spec:

```
GET users/:user
```

Means:

```
GET users/:user.id
```

This works:

https://wakatime.com/api/v1/users/f0fbed96-0c45-4d01-89e4-6a595a23299b?api_key=XXXX

I've got user ID from:

https://wakatime.com/api/v1/users/current?api_key=XXX

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to assign the Points, just did it !

Comment: Both user_id and username are supported in the api since Nov 2015, so your original url will also work now.